# How to export a mesh with skeleton as FBX for UE4?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, bones, unreal-engine

i would like to export this mesh as an FBX file.
So far i'm able to export the static mesh but without the skeleton.
It looks like there are many "lines" but only 8-9 bones for the wheels. This Control Panel is able to move the wings and cabin glass but has no bones like the wheels. There are also many other moving things.
When i export the bones as FBX it's empty and i'm unable to open or export it to UE4.

I don't know what more i need to explain.
I just want to export the mesh and the skeleton so i will be able to make animations inside Unreal Engine 4.

[image]
[image]
[image]